# How do you work out the prefix key for a mode map and major mode in which it is activated?

Tags: key-bindings, keymap

Given the name of a keymap how do you work out the prefix key for the keymap, and the mode in which that keymap can be activated?

In the example below `org-mode-map`, `C-c v` and `<f6>` are the required values.

```
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c v") some-mode-map)
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<f6>") some-mode-map)
```

Comment: Keymaps don't have "a leader key".  You can bind any number of keys in keymap.  Leader keys are a concept layered on top of keymaps (I've heard the term used in connection with "Spacemacs") whereby (IIUC) a keymap with only one top-level binding is used; but that's an entirely artificial constraint.

Comment: What @phils said. The question is unclear so far. In particular, please clarify wrt "leader key" or remove that. But it's also unclear what you mean by the mode map which is activated.

Comment: @phils By `leader key` I mean the `C-c v` or the `<f6>` that is required to activate `some-mode-map`. informally it is the key pressed in `org-mode-map` that causes `which-key` to display all the commands present in `some-mode-map`. Is there a formal term for it?

Comment: "Prefix key [binding]" is the Emacs term for a key which is bound to a keymap.  Note that whether or not the keymap is the value of a variable is irrelevant -- in your example `C-c` is also a prefix binding, and the underlying structure is identical: In org-mode-map `C-c` is bound to a keymap which includes `v` which in turn is bound to a keymap which happens to be the value of your variable.

Comment: See also `C-h i g (elisp)Prefix Keys`

Comment: Pressing `C-c` does not “activate” `org-mode-map`. There can be multiple keymaps containing bindings with the prefix `C-c`. When you press `C-c C-h`, it lists all the bindings starting with `C-c` and they can come from several different keymaps.